# No image when saving outlook .msg with olSaveAsType olMsg

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm trying to build and save a message with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`.

I build with an HTML body and include my image like that :

```
msg.HTMLBody = String.Format(body, "Screenshot0.png", "Screenshot1.png", "Screenshot2.png", "Signature.png");


public void attachImg(Outlook.MailItem msg,int index)
    {
        int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
        Outlook.Attachment img1 = msg.Attachments.Add(
                @"\\img\path"
                , iAttachType
                , null
                , "Perf CCE Presta");
        string image = "Screenshot" + index + ".png";
        img1.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", image);
    }
```

When I use `Display();` method, my message display correctly with pictures.
Nevertheless when I use `msg.SaveAs(\\my\path\name.msg)` and then open the file, i got the msg without the pictures.

I tried with `msg.SaveAs(\\my\path\name.msg,Outlook.olSaveAsType.olMsg)`and have same result

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call `MailItem.Save` before calling `MailItem.SaveAs`.

Comment: Unbelievable, I lost one afternoon because of that. Thank you, it works now !